# jquery plugin Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just created my first `jQuery plugin` , it is very simple it `slideToggle` two `Divs` , the code works fine and it do what i want , the problem is that i get an `ERROR` message at the console saying :

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

it refer to this line of code

```
})(jQuery);
```

**CODE**

```
   $(function($) {
            $.fn.toggleDiv = function(opt) {
                var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.toggleDiv.objectOptions, opt);
                return this.each(function() {
                    if (options.animation == true) {
                        $(this).slideToggle();

                    } else {
                        $(this).toggle();

                    }
                });
            };

            $.fn.toggleDiv.objectOptions = {
                animation: false
            };
            $("button").click(function() { $("#Div1, #Div2")
             .toggleDiv({animation : fa}); return false; });
        })(jQuery);
```

Does any one know what is that error and how can i fix it thanks

Comment: Removing the very first `$` help ?

Comment: `})(jQuery);` should be `}(jQuery));` with removing first `$`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You either want to do

```
(function ($) { ... })(jQuery);
```

if you want your code to be run immediatly,

or

```
jQuery(function ($) { .... });
```

for your code to be run on document-ready.

You are referring to $("button"), and therefore need the document tree to be available. So use the second version. A even nicer solution would be to use the jQuery function "delegate", this would look something like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).delegate("button", "click", function (ev) { ... });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dietrich. Simple and clear answer. Helped me too right now.